# Qt Creator cannot resolve gvContext on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt-creator, graphviz

I want to write an application in C++ that displays an automaton using graphviz. I tried out a sample taken from documentation but I get 'undefined reference gvContext', along with the other function calls. The sample code I tried is :

```
void create_automaton(int argc, char *argv[]){

Agraph_t *g;
Agnode_t *n, *m;
Agedge_t *e;
Agsym_t *a;
GVC_t *gvc;

gvc = gvContext();

gvParseArgs(gvc, argc, argv);

g = agopen("g", Agdirected, 0);
n = agnode(g, "n", 1);
m = agnode(g, "m", 1);
e = agedge(g, n, m, 0, 1);

agsafeset(n, "color", "red", "");
gvLayoutJobs(gvc, g);
gvRenderJobs(gvc, g);

gvFreeLayout(gvc, g);

agclose(g);


}
```

I included  without which the variable types wouldn't have been recognized, but which doesn't make a difference for my issue. I thought about linking library to the project but this is obviously not the problem since the program detects the header. 
It is a beginner question, but I would really appreciate if someone has an idea about this. I couldn't find anything significant on the internet, all other similar problems I've found had the solution of installing graphviz-dev, which I already have.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: show your .pro.

Comment: add `LIBS += -lgvc -lcgraph -lcdt` to .pro

Comment: Thanks, it works :)

Comment: Do you know what would be an appropriate value for argv? I know it has to be a terminal dot command like 'dot -Tpng filename.dot -o outfile.png' but in this case I have no .dot file since I generate the graph in code and I render it.