# How to properly link Graphviz in a c++ application on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, graphviz

I am having problems compiling simple example code taken from the official website here https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/dot.demo/demo.c .The problem is undefined reference to Graphviz functions. I know there is a related question asked here [Qt Creator cannot resolve gvContext on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321412/qt-creator-cannot-resolve-gvcontext-on-ubuntu), but it didn't help.

I have included libgvc libcgraph libcdt in my CMakeLists.txt and that did't help. I have made sure that these packages are present on my machine.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(name)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(name main.cpp)

INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(gvc REQUIRED libgvc libcgraph libcdt)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${gvc_LIBRARY_DIRS})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${gvc_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${gvc_LIBRARIES})
```

Please if someone linked the library or knows how to link correctly, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install the `libgraphviz-dev` package? That contains the `libgvc` pkg-config file your CMakeLists.txt needs.

Comment: With your CMake file and that package, I could compile that demo.c file. Can you show the output of `make VERBOSE=1` ?

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly why (I think I made a typo in CMakeLists.txt), but I compiled this too now, thanks.